# How can I wait for a button to be visible?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I need to click on a button that is only visible after validating the email, phone and name fields.
I don't want to use "WAIT".
I also used "VISIBILITYCHECK" `(this.buttonOk = Selector('button',{ visibilityCheck: true }).withText('Ok');)`, but it didn't work.

[Tela com os campos nome, email e telefone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMxIf.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Selector Timeout](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402829/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements#selector-timeout) for this.